# dashboard prompt doesn't work in obiee 11g when using javascript

Tags: obiee

I am using obiee 11g.
I have a dashboard with some sections. 
I am using javascript code embedded in a text object (contains HTML marked) within the section. The javascript code I use is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
saw.dashboard.onToggleSection('<your-section-id-here>',null);
</script>
```

The aim is to collapse the sections by default and it works fine. 
but after I did this, when I select dashboard prompt value, the value could not be passed to reports.
Could anyone tell how to fix it.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

That's always the problem when you start scripting something which you aren't supposed to touch in the first place.

Remember that you're doing data anlytics with this tool. You're not creating a vanity "app". Think about what's the actual goal and educate your users.

Comment: you are right about the fact scripting is not the solution. But if OBI have a possibility to collapse/uncollapse some analytics, I can't understand why they don't have put the possibility to choose if it has to be collapse as default or not ! Do you have another solution?

Comment: "why they don't have put the possibility to choose if it has to be collapse as default or not ! "

Because that's what's called user customization which then are stored in saved customizations.